# Erro com formatação condicional se documento aberto no Microsoft Office

Tags: php, phpexcel, formatação-condicional

Ao aplicar formatação condicional a uma folha de calculo `xlsx` gerada com o [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel), a mesma funciona sem problemas quando o documeno é aberto no [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/):

```php
$objConditional = new PHPExcel_Style_Conditional();

$objConditional->setConditionType(PHPExcel_Style_Conditional::CONDITION_CELLIS)
               ->setOperatorType(PHPExcel_Style_Conditional::OPERATOR_EQUAL)
               ->addCondition('='.$index_min_cell);

$objConditional->getStyle()->getFont()->getColor()->setRGB('FFFFFF');
$objConditional->getStyle()->getFont()->setSize(8);
$objConditional->getStyle()->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getEndColor()->setRGB('5c8526');
$objConditional->getStyle()->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode("[$$-409]#,##0.00;-[$$-409]#,##0.00");


$explode=explode(',', $condition_min_med);

for ($m=0; $m<count($explode); $m++) {
    $sheet_00->getStyle($explode[$m])->setConditionalStyles(array($objConditional));
}
```

Mas quando o documento é aberto utilizando o Microsoft Office, o mesmo apresenta o seguinte erro *rico em informação*:

> Funcionalidade Removida: Formatação condicional da parte /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml

Com Link para um XML com a seguinte informação:

```xml
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
  <logFileName>error033680_04.xml</logFileName>
  <summary>Foram detectados erros no ficheiro 'C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local\Temp\super_bubu.xlsx'</summary>
  <removedFeatures summary="Segue-se uma lista de funcionalidades removidas:">
    <removedFeature>Funcionalidade Removida: Formatação condicional da parte /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml</removedFeature>
  </removedFeatures>
</recoveryLog>
```

## Pergunta

Dado que a informação relativa ao erro apenas indica que foi removida a funcionalidade, e tendo em conta que o documento quando aberto no LibreOffice funciona sem problemas fazendo uso da formatação condicional aplicada:

Qual o motivo pelo qualquer o [Microsoft Office Excel 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/quick-start-apply-conditional-formatting-HA010370614.aspx) ignora a formatação condicional que está a ser aplicada ?

---

<sup>**Nota:**

Isto é parte de um ficheiro muito extenso que trata de gerar toda a folha de calculo, mas esta parte em particular, se removida, faz com que o Excel deixe de apresentar o erro... Claro que a formatação condicional não está lá!</sup>

Comment: Em qual versão do excel foi feito o teste? a planilha está no formato do excel5 ou 2007?

Comment: @perdeu O ficheiro que está a ser gerado é um `XLSX` e está a ser testado no Excel 2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aparentemente, para o Microsoft Office Excel, ao definirmos o tipo de operador, não podemos indicar o mesmo operador na condição:

**Onde está:**

```php
$objConditional->setConditionType(PHPExcel_Style_Conditional::CONDITION_CELLIS)
               ->setOperatorType(PHPExcel_Style_Conditional::OPERATOR_EQUAL)
               ->addCondition('='.$index_min_cell);
```

**Alterar para:**

```php
$objConditional->setConditionType(PHPExcel_Style_Conditional::CONDITION_CELLIS)
               ->setOperatorType(PHPExcel_Style_Conditional::OPERATOR_EQUAL)
               ->addCondition($index_min_cell);
```

---

Ou seja, como já definimos através do `setOperatorType()` o operador pretendido:

```php
->setOperatorType(PHPExcel_Style_Conditional::OPERATOR_EQUAL)
```

Não devemos aplicar o mesmo na condição através do `addCondition()`:

```php
->addCondition('='.$index_min_cell);
```

deve ficar apenas a condição pretendida:

```php
->addCondition($index_min_cell);
```

---

Pelo que entendi, o LibreOffice ao encontrar o tipo de operador `OPERATOR_EQUAL` e a condição precedida pelo operador `=`, deixa ficar apenas um `=` na construção da condição.

O Microsoft Office Excel, suspeito que tente fazer do tipo `==condição`, e por não interpretar isso, rebenta-se todo e ignora a formatação condicional por completo.